# Processing more than one user comment form using mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, comments

I've been coding for only 6 weeks so please bear with me.

Yes, I have searched a lot but perhaps I don't know enough to word my queries effectively. 
If you can read on and perhaps advise me how to word my searches that would be awesome help. I am starting from scratch and doing everything myself.
My question is basically conceptual and won't need my code.

I have a project website on my local host, using PHP MySQL. I want comment boxes/forms under EACH article (Without signing in ATM) to comment.

SO FAR (6 weeks remember): After html and css + content, I have successfully included 'comment.php' (html comment form) on my page in this "comment.php" includes "list_comments.php". "comment.php" then actions to comment_form.php this guy inserts to a Mysql database table 3 values $name, $email, $comment plus the ID. The "header" redirects back to "comment.php". List_comments.php selects and echos the Name and comment. Awesome, I'm feeling happy with my progress. 
However, obviously, if I try to include this more than once around the site the comments all appear everywhere the list_comments is.

Short of creating new database and new forms each time I'm not sure conceptually how to go about it, I know it's possible do it another way.
My question is basically I have one how do I do two?
If you could point me in the right direction or even tell me the correct way to phrase a search I would be relieved and grateful.
Thanks in advance.
Trev

Comment: Uh....we all sent our crystal balls out to be cleaned earlier. Give each list its own id and filter by that id when you need to show the data in a particular place.

Comment: "My question is basically conceptual and won't need my code." then this is probably not the best place to ask

Comment: I got lost in this line _"The "header" redirects back to "comment.php""_ what header?

Comment: Ok thanks. Never mind about the header comment.

Comment: Where would be a good place to ask, might be a nice addition to the statement above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure if I fully understand your question so I'll summarize what I think you are trying to ask?  You have added the ability to add comments to a specific article.  Now you want to extend the functionality to additional articles without having to copy and paste everything.....

If this is your question, here is a possible solution.
1.  Create a single php page for the articles called article.php (or whatever you like)
2.  Create a minimum of 2 tables in the MySQL database for this site.
    a.  articles - a table that has a column for each dynamic part of the articles plus a primary key column.  For example, (id, title, content, date added).
    b.  comments - a table that has a column for primary key (id), comment and article id
3.  You will have to have an additional web page that allows you to navigate the different articles.  A simple way would be to link to them with something like /article.php?id=.  Then article.php would use the $_GET['id'] to determine the article id used in the database lookup and also look for comments with the same article id in the comments database table....

There are 1000 ways to skin this but you are off to a good start.  I think the missing piece is you've made comments dynamic but didn't know how to relate the comments to a specific article.  Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thank you, really that's helped a lot you understood exactly what I needed my terminology is not up to scratch but you gave me the right advice, the ball is rolling again. Cheers for the "off to a good start". Good Luck. If there's other ways people can keep commenting but I'll be busy for a while.

Comment: How do I link a url with the ?id=1/2 with a localhost for example I cant save php file as .php?id=1

Comment: So you will have to read a little bit about passing post and get parameters in php.  Basically, you can have a page like index.php.  Other pages can link to index.php with a <a href=index.php?id=1>Click to go to index</a>.  The index.php page will receive a $_GET['id'] parameter equal to 1 that you can use to lookup the article in the database.  However, if you wanted a single page with multiple articles you would want to do something different completely like maybe use a foreach loop with each article id.  Not really sure what you are trying to do exactly.....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then your database schema (layout of tables) doesn't allow for a user to have more than one comment.

You should be thinking about this in an "object-oriented" way. In your example, you would have two objects. A "User" and a "Comment". A "User" has many "Comments.

You could implement this pattern in your database using a "users" table, and a "comments" table. Each "comment" row would have a "user_id" field, which would associate the comment to the unique ID of the user that posted it.

How you implement this in your PHP code is up to you.

Research [Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), [Object Relational Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), and [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Great stuff mate, I'm reading and practicing OOP and taking a basic course on on PHP with codecademy (not sure if its the best). I'll be adding ORM and database normalisation to my things to study asap. You've offered some useful advice.

Comment: Hey no problem. Upvote for a new user? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REUukm_WQJI